# bash script to translate XML

Tags: xml, bash, scripting

Hi I have dozens of XML files with
I would need this:

```
<p begin="00:06:28;12" end="00:00:02;26">
```

translated into this:

```
<p begin="628.12" end="631.08">
```

I know i need a simple awk or sed to do this, but being new; can someone help

Comment: What's the relationship between the old and new values?

Comment: Shouldn't the end value be 630.38?

Comment: it is the start time in mm:ss and end is the elapsed time
   <p begin="8:08.15" end="04.25">

becomes

 <p begin="488.15" end="493.10">

to do this I take the 8:   meaning 8 minutes and multiply by 60 seconds to get  480 seconds.  Then I add the 08 seconds to get 488 and add the .15

Comment: Your format has just totally changed, surely <p begin="00:08:08;15" end="00:00:04;25"> would become 488.15 and end would be 492.40, which comes from. 488 + 4 = 492. And add the ms together .25 + .15 = .40. That correct?

Comment: @code_acdc - the example in the question looks wrong - shouldn't "06:28;12" map to (6*60+28) = 388.12?  Can you confirm that the number after the semicolon is a frame number in the range 0-29?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah ghostdog74 beat me to it. However mine also deals with the ms.

```
awk '
    function timeToMin(str) {
        time_re = "([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]);([0-9][0-9])"

        # Grab all the times in seconds. 
        s_to_s =  gensub(time_re, "\\3", "g", str);
        m_to_s = (gensub(time_re, "\\2", "g", str)+0)*60;
        h_to_s = (gensub(time_re, "\\1", "g", str)+0)*60*60;
        ms     =  gensub(time_re, "\\4", "g", str);

        # Create float.
        time_str = (h_to_s+m_to_s+s_to_s)"."ms;

        # Converts from num to str.
        return time_str+0; 
    }
    function addMins(aS, bS) {
        # Split by decimal point
        split(aS, aP, ".");
        split(bS, bP, ".");

        # Add the seconds and ms.
        min = aP[1]+bP[1];
        ms  = aP[2]+bP[2];
        if (ms > 59) {
            ms = ms-60;
            mins++;
        }

        # Return addition.
        return (min"."ms)+0;
    }
    {
        re = "<p begin=\"(.+)\" end=\"(.+)\">";
        if ($0 ~ re) {
            # Pull out the data.
            strip_re = ".*"re".*";
            begin_str = gensub(strip_re, "\\1", "g");
            end_str   = gensub(strip_re, "\\2", "g");

            # Convert.
            begin = timeToMin(begin_str);
            end   = timeToMin(end_str);

            elapsed_end=addMins(begin, end);

            sub(re,"<p begin=\""begin"\" end=\""elapsed_end"\">");
        }

        print $0;
    }
' file
```

Comment: If the down vote was for the disapproval of using awk, usually I'd agree however if its a one off script then I can't see any reason not to.

Comment: this solution doesn't seem to work
if input is <p begin="19.22" end="03.01"> the output is <p begin="70364.4" end="81383.1"> which is not correct

Comment: the regex should be time_re = "([0-9][0-9])?:?([0-9][0-9])?:?([0-9][0-9])?;?([0-9][0-9])?" and return time_str+0; should be return time_str; else 32.20 + 5.01 will be taken as 32.2 + 5.01

Comment: This script is an gawk script but I am on a mac and it doesn't recognize the gensub function. Any work arounds.

Answer (score 5):

An XSL stylesheet would be more reliable. You can run one from a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

here's something for a start. I don't know how you want to add the decimal value, so you do it yourself

```
awk '/.*<p[ ]+begin=.*[ ]+end=.*/{
    o=$0
    gsub(/.*begin=\042|\042|>/,"")
    m=split($0,s,"end=")
    gsub(/[:;]/," ",s[1])
    gsub(/[:;]/," ",s[2])
    b=split(s[1],begin," ")
    e=split(s[2],end," ")
    # do date maths here
    if (b>3){
        tbegin=(begin[1]*3600) + (begin[2]*60) + begin[3]  ##"."begin[4]
    }else{
        tbegin=(begin[1]*60) + begin[3]  ##"."begin[4]
    }
    # add the decimal yourself
    if(e>3) {
        tend = (end[1]*3600) +(end[2]*60)+end[3]+ tbegin ##"."end[4]
    }else{
        tend = (end[1]*60)+end[3]+ tbegin ##"."end[4]
    }
    string=gensub("(.*begin=\042).*( end=\042)(.*)\042>", "\\1" tbegin "\042\\2" tend"\042>","g",o)
    $0=string
}
{print}
' file
```

eg

```
$ cat file
<p begin="00:06:28;12" end="00:00:02;26">
<p begin="00:08:45;12" end="00:00:23;26">
<p begin="08:45;12" end="00:2;26">

$ ./shell.sh
<p begin="388" end="390">
<p begin="525" end="548">
<p begin="492" end="518">
```

If you are doing more complex tasks other than this, use a parser.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Perl (or another scripting language) with an XML parsing module (see [here](http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/) for more details on Perl and XML).

That way you can *reliably* parse the XML and extract/manipulate the values in a programmatic form. Note the word reliably. Your XML may make use of character encodings that a simple sed/awk wouldn't respect (unlikely in this scenario, admittedly, but it's well worth being aware of such issues).